# Popups set via Hustle plugins but not working properly on website creating in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Popups set via Hustle plugins but not working properly.

I'm creating a website on Wordpress using Elementor, where I used the Hustle plugin for popups contact form. Previously it was working properly but when I added some more columns in it. The popups is not working properly. Even I cross checked within the hustle plugin as well as also updated the same.
Can anyone help me?